# I would like to write the most efficient code to import Microsoft SQL data to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to load a SQL query into a data frame as efficiently as possible. I read different sources and everyone seems to use a different approach. I am not sure why... Some are using cursors some aren't.

Currently I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={something};'
    'Server=something;'
    'Database=something;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)

sql="""
SQL CODE
"""

df = pd.read_sql_query(con,sql)
```

And for some reason, this doesn't work in my machine.

Comment: Hi, when you say, "this doesn't work," what do you mean? What error message is generated? Are you able to connect to the server via other means, e.g. command line or server management program?

Comment: Can you manage to connect to the database from your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pack it in a function. Also I add username and password (just in case)

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

def GetSQLData(dbName, query):

    sPass = 'MyPassword'
    sServer = 'MyServer\\SQL1'
    uname = 'MyUser'

    cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                    "Server=" + sServer + ";"
                    "Database=" + dbName + ";"
                    "uid=" + uname + ";pwd=" + sPass)


    df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)

    return df
```

Comment: I have the following error message:
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string
' sql statement....'

Comment: Oh sorry , I edit the answer, I think it's related with the read_sql parameters order!

Comment: I can't know what is happening, recheck you connection string

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=something;"
                      "Database=something;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")


cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM something')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={something};'
    'Server=something;'
    'Database=something;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)

cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute("SQL Syntax")
```

Not quite sure what your last line is doing, but the cursor method works well and runs with efficiently with minimal code.

This should run. You can test it by adding in sqllist = list(cursor.fetchall()) and then print(sqllist)